# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Lenovo X250 - sound issues

Tags: wireless, sound, 16.04, soundcard

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Lenovo X250, and the maximum volume is low in respect to when I was using Windows. Are the known issues with the soundcard of Lenovo x250 with Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. You can find solutions for both issues by using search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the sound over 100% ? In the sound parameters you can tick a box that allow to have a louder volume.
I have the same computer and installed 16.04 yesterday and have no sound issues, it was actually really low before I have done this. But after ticking that box, the volume is loud enough.

Comment: It would seem odd that he would **have** to set the volume over 100% to get the same volume as in Windows.